# Multi-threading, consumers and producers

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, unix

I have a problem with multithreading, since I'm new to this topic. Code below is code I've been given from my University. It was in few versions, and I understood most of them. But I don't really understand the nready.nready variable and all this thread condition. Can anyone describe how those two work here? And why can't I just synchronise work of threads via mutex?

```
#include    "unpipc.h"

#define MAXNITEMS       1000000
#define MAXNTHREADS         100

    /* globals shared by threads */
int     nitems;             /* read-only by producer and consumer */
int     buff[MAXNITEMS];

struct {
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
pthread_cond_t  cond;
int             nput;
int             nval;
int             nready;
} nready = { PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER, PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER };

void    *produce(void *), *consume(void *);

/* include main */
int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
int         i, nthreads, count[MAXNTHREADS];
pthread_t   tid_produce[MAXNTHREADS], tid_consume;

if (argc != 3)
    err_quit("usage: prodcons5 <#items> <#threads>");
nitems = min(atoi(argv[1]), MAXNITEMS);
nthreads = min(atoi(argv[2]), MAXNTHREADS);

Set_concurrency(nthreads + 1);
    /* 4create all producers and one consumer */
for (i = 0; i < nthreads; i++) {
    count[i] = 0;
    Pthread_create(&tid_produce[i], NULL, produce, &count[i]);
}
Pthread_create(&tid_consume, NULL, consume, NULL);

    /* wait for all producers and the consumer */
for (i = 0; i < nthreads; i++) {
    Pthread_join(tid_produce[i], NULL);
    printf("count[%d] = %d\n", i, count[i]);    
}
Pthread_join(tid_consume, NULL);

exit(0);
}
/* end main */

void *
produce(void *arg)
{
    for ( ; ; ) {
    Pthread_mutex_lock(&nready.mutex);
    if (nready.nput >= nitems) {
        Pthread_mutex_unlock(&nready.mutex);
        return(NULL);       /* array is full, we're done */
    }
    buff[nready.nput] = nready.nval;
    nready.nput++;
    nready.nval++;
    nready.nready++;
    Pthread_cond_signal(&nready.cond);
    Pthread_mutex_unlock(&nready.mutex);
    *((int *) arg) += 1;
}
}

/* include consume */
void *
consume(void *arg)
{
int     i;

for (i = 0; i < nitems; i++) {
    Pthread_mutex_lock(&nready.mutex);
    while (nready.nready == 0)
        Pthread_cond_wait(&nready.cond, &nready.mutex);
    nready.nready--;
    Pthread_mutex_unlock(&nready.mutex);

    if (buff[i] != i)
        printf("buff[%d] = %d\n", i, buff[i]);
}
return(NULL);
}
/* end consume */
```

Comment: Most processes would be brought to their knees by 200 threads.

Comment: what does the function call: Set_concurrency(nthreads + 1); actually do?  Why are the standard pthread function names been replaced with same spelling but different capitalication functions?

Comment: Once again, it's not my code. I've been given it to learn and understand threads.

Comment: @user3629249 Only if all 200 of them want to run at the same time and there are considerably less than 200 CPUs available. On the other hand, there are lots of examples out there of programs running hundreds and even thousands of threads, as long as the majority of them spend most of their time sleeping while waiting for certain events (incoming network connections, disk I/O, keyboard input, ...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&nready.mutex);
while (nready.nready == 0)
    pthread_cond_wait(&nready.cond, &nready.mutex);
nready.nready--;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&nready.mutex);
```

The whole point of this structure is to guarantee that the condition (nready.nready == 0) is still true when you execute the corresponding action (nready.nready--) or - if the condition is not satisfied - to wait until it is without using CPU time.

You could use a mutex only, to check that the condition is correct and to perform the corresponding action atomically. But if the condition is not satisfied, you wouldn't know what to do. Wait? Until when? Check it again? Release the mutex and re-check immediately after? That would be wasting CPU time...

pthread_cond_signal() and pthread_cond_wait() are here to solve this problem. You should check their man pages.

Briefly, what pthread_cond_wait does, is it puts the calling thread to sleep and release the mutex in an atomic way until it's signaled. So this is a blocking function. The thread can then be re-scheduled by calling signal or broadcast from a different thread. When the thread is signaled, it grabs the mutex again and exit the wait() function.

Ath this point you know that

1. your condition is true and
2. you hold the mutex.

So you can do whatever you need to do with your data.

Be careful though, you shouldn't call wait, if you're not sure that another thread will signal. This is a very common source of deadlocks.

When a thread received a signal, it's put on the list of threads that are ready to be scheduled. By the time the thread is actually executed, your condition (i.e. nread.nready == 0) may be false again. Hence the while (to recheck if the thread is waked).

Comment: Ok, I think it settles it. I just need to reconsider it all in my head. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
"But I don't really understand the nready.nready variable"

this results from the struct instance being named 'nready' and there 
is a field within the struct named 'nready'

IMO: a very poor design to have two different objects being given the same name

the nready field of the nready struct seems to be keeping track of the number of 
items that have been 'produced'
```

Comment: The problem was more like what nready does and why is it needed at all.

Answer (score 0):

1) The `nready` filed of `struct nready` is used to tack how many tasks are ready to consume, i.e., the remaining tasks in array `buff`. The `nready.nready++;` statement is only executed when producers put one new item in array `buff`, and the `nready.nready--;` is only executed when consume gets item out of `buff`. With is variable, programmer can always track how many tasks are there left to process.

2)

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&nready.mutex);
while (nready.nready == 0)
    pthread_cond_wait(&nready.cond, &nready.mutex);
nready.nready--;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&nready.mutex);
```

The statements above are common condition variable usage. You can check
[POSIX Threads Programming](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConVarOverview) and [Condition Variables](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/NSF-3/e-Book/MONITOR/CV.html) for more about condition variables.

Why can't use mutex only? You can poll a mutex lock again and again. Obviously, it is CPU time consuming and may be hugely affect system performance. Instead, you want the consume to wait in sleep when there is no more items in `buff`, and to be awaken when producer puts new item in `buff`. The condition variable is acting as this role here. When there is no items (nready.nready==0), `pthread_cond_wait()` function puts the current thread into sleep, save the precious cpu time. When new items are arriving, `Pthread_cond_signal()` awakes the consumer.